# Simple dynamic router get method doesn't work

Tags: php

I am busy with a small test case and want to make my own routes. So when I execute `www.domain.com/users` I want to make an object with the index method called. So I can pass data from thee index method to the view/template.

How can I get `$class->index()` dynamically in the route?

```
Router::route('/users' , 'UsersController@index');
Router::execute($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

class Router {

    private static $routes = array();

    private function __construct() {}
    private function __clone() {}

    public static function route($pattern, $callback) {
        $pattern = $pattern;
        self::$routes[$pattern] = $callback;
    }

    public static function execute($url) {
        foreach (self::$routes as $pattern => $callback) {
            if($pattern==$url){
                $callback = explode('@' , $callback);

                $fullclass = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\Controllers\\' . $callback[0];
                $class = new $fullclass;
                ---- Here is my problem ----
                $method = "index()";
                $class->$method.'()';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code may be rewritten like this:

```
$method = "index";
$class->$method();
```

Also have a look here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

```
// Call the $foo->bar() method with 2 arguments
$foo = new foo;
call_user_func_array(array($foo, "bar"), array("three", "four"));
```

Comment: Additionally, read here: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php